# Is it possible to restrict which external domains php's cURL library may access?

Tags: php, curl

My web application uses cURL to communicate with an external domain. There's only one external domain with which the application may connect and communicate. Is it possible to restrict which external domains the PHP cURL library may access as an extra measure of security in the application's environment?

Comment: is the external domain hard codded? if yes there is no problem

Comment: no. not in curl itself. curl's job is to fetch whatever you tell it to. restricting what places can be fetched from/sent to is outside curl's purview. that's something you do before curl ever gets involved, e.g. `if (is_allowed($url)) { do_curl(); }`. or do something like setting an outgoing firewall rule so that the php process is only allowed to open connections to a particular IP. but note that the firewall can't tell between you doing a raw `fsockopen()` or doing `curl_init(...)`. it's just a socket like any other.

Comment: @Dagon the external domain is hard coded, but I'd like to reduce the risk of another php script communicating with any other external domain.

Comment: that really does not make sense to me. if you are in control of the scripts and sever - than what can happen? if your not, then there is never going to be anything you can do

Comment: @Dagon sure, this is true, but if you're not the only one in control of scripts and server?

Comment: then anything you add to stop other domains, could also be removed. and if they have code\site access they could do a lot worse than change the site your curl is hitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically this can be done by defining a function in a users shell:

```
Mac Shell: Downloads/>$ curl(){
> echo "test";
> }
Mac Shell: Downloads/>$ curl
test
Mac Shell: Downloads/>$ which curl
/usr/bin/curl
Mac Shell: Downloads/>$ type -a curl
curl is a function
curl () 
{ 
    echo "test"
}
curl is /usr/bin/curl
Mac Shell: Downloads/>$
```

Ergo you could do something like this:

```
curl(){
    domain="$1"
    [[ "$domain" == "mydomain.com" ]] && {
        /usr/bin/curl "$domain";
    } || {
        printf "That is not the domain that you are supposed to use\n";
    };
};
```

As long as the user does not specify the file path this should work.

I would not recommend this though.

### Edit:

Here is verification of this solution:

```
Mac Shell: Downloads/>$ curl(){
>     domain="$1"
>     [[ "$domain" == "mydomain.com" ]] && {
>         /usr/bin/curl "$domain";
>     } || {
>         printf "That is not the domain that you are supposed to use\n";
>     };
> };
Mac Shell: Downloads/>$ curl test
That is not the domain that you are supposed to use
Mac Shell: Downloads/>$ curl mydomain.com
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>301 Moved Permanently</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Moved Permanently</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="URL">here</A>.<P>
</BODY></HTML>
Mac Shell: Downloads/>$
```

### Edit2:

This would also have to be sourced.

For instance if you put this ins a `.bash_profie` file for a certain user (There are other more creative places that you could put this) then you would have to logout and back in to see the effects or type:

```
source /<some_path>/.bash_profile
```

### Edit3:

Just to clarify for everyone this is a proof of concept.  A much more extensive logic test will be needed.  For example if the person tried to curl this domain with a different subdomain or port, path, query, or fragment the provided logic test would fail.

**Again I would not recommend limiting a user in this way.**

Answer (score 0):

just make a whitelist and parse the url with parse_url

```
$whitelist=array('www.facebook.com','facebook.com','www.google.com','google.com','www.microsoft.com');
if(!in_array(parse_url($external,PHP_URL_HOST)??'',$whitelist)){
//domain is not whitelisted
} else {
//domain is whitelisted.
$ch=curl_init($external);
}
```